# Debugging C++/Cli: <Unknown function> and no Locals

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I am trying to debug a project with a C# assembly and a C++/Cli assembly.

An interface defined in C# is inherited by a C++/Cli class, which in turn calls a native C++ class. Mixed-mode debugging is enabled in both C++ and C# assembly, as well as the startup .exe.

Now, when I try to debug into the C++ part, it gets tricky; if I simply set breakpoints in the C++ part, they are not hit (despite the fact that I know that they are hit because logs (etc) are written and throwing an exception there actually will throw it properly).

When I set a breakpoint at the latest call in C# before the call to the mixed-mode assembly, I can step into the C++/Cli code, and even into the native part. However, the Call stack is shown as

```
MyMixedMode.dll!<Unknown function> Line ...
```

and I cannot inspect any locals (the locals view is just empty while inside the native code).

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately pieces of the tooling support in VS for C++/CLI projects keep falling off, they are struggling to keep it maintained.  There's an issue with the new debug engine added to VS2012, the one that supports the new [C++ debugging visualizers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/07/12/10329460.aspx), it doesn't support C++/CLI anymore.

VS2012 Update 1 added a new setting in Tools + Options, Debugging, General, named "Managed C++ Compatibility Mode".  Confusingly renamed to "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" in VS2013.  Undocumented in the MSDN page for this settings page.  What it does is force the debugger to use the old debugging engine instead of the new one.

This does have a side-effect, those shiny new debugging visualizers won't work when you have the option turned on.  Keep this in mind if the debug info for your native code doesn't look right.

Comment: Do you know if support for C++/Cli in the new debugging engine is at least planned?

Comment: Microsoft *never* shares its development plans.  Microsoft employees usually know, they are however forbidden from sharing that knowledge.  So no.

Comment: Actually, this seems to affect all mixed mode debugging. We have a mixed C++/C# application where we use COM for interop and it exhibits the same issue. This solved it for me as well.

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution: The mixed-mode debugging setting on the projects is not enough alone, in addition, Visual Studio requires enabling

```
[x] Use Managed Compatibility Mode
```

in Tool->Options->Debugging->General.

Comment: most interesting. How did you find that? Do you have any links to MSDN or similar that describe that problem? Please share the links!

Comment: I've erased a part of my comment, because I've just remembered!:) They were not hit, because (I guess from my observations) the managed runtime does not know where to really set them until the native code is called. Placed beforewards, they became marked as "disabled/at wrong address". But if placed after you stepped into the C++ part (whatever, even the functions prologue), it would work. I always thought of it as some sort of limitation when working with mixed debugging. Or maybe address randomization sideeffect? Thank you very much for finding that flag. I'll surely try it out next time.

Comment: I wish I had good links or so, but it was random luck. I thought maybe it was missing the breakpoints because of lacking support so I added a _declspec export macro to the C++ class. After doing that, VS popped up a dialog informing me I should enable that option. It didn't do it all the tries before...

Comment: This trick does seem to work but the problem with it is that Edit & Continue doesn't work after this change.