# Which project types or settings control availability of "return value inspection"?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

As a C++ programmer, I'm used to being able to see return values in the debugger. But when I was working in C# (before VS 2013), I wasn't able to. As a result I have a pretty casual attitude about the whole thing: sometimes they're there, sometimes they're not. They are actually supposed to be there in VS 2013, and I think I remember seeing them, but it's not really a big deal.

But now I am writing a simple demo showing this feature and (Murphy being in full effect) can't make it happen in any of the C# code I happen to have kicking around. I've even copied the source code from [the MSDN page about the feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn323257.aspx), built a console app and run it, without seeing these values in the Autos window. (And no, I don't always just stop right there, I've tried stopping sooner and stepping over.) As you can see in the screenshot, $ReturnValue in the Immediate Window doesn't work either.

Clearly this feature works for some people and some projects. So, what controls it? What do I need to do to make it happen?

[image: Visual Studio debugging]

Comment: I don't have VS 2013 installed currently to test this, but this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/26/announcing-the-net-framework-4-5-1-preview.aspx) and [UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2206747-function-return-value-in-debugger) imply that it will only work if you target the 4.5.**1** CLR. Would be worth a try if your project isn't targeted to this version.

Comment: That got me excited but I am sorry to report that changing the target framework didn't help.

Comment: OK got VS 2013 installed now. Overdue anyway. It seems like this feature only works if you explicitly step into (F11) `Method1()` or `Method2()` from `Main()`. If you only place a BP inside these methods (doesn't matter where), the feature does not seem to kick in. Could be intentional (maybe for performance reasons), but almost seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Still no luck. So you have a reproducible works and doesn't work flow? I have only doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: Actually I just noticed it's more specific. What doesn't work (for me anyway) is: Jumping from one BP to another using F5. What works is: Actually stepping over the lines using F10 where the demo says "1. Step over the following line".

Comment: I have tried many combinations now including the exact instructions in the demo and none of it shows the return values ever. So annoying!

Answer (score 0):

The feature is missing (as well as 64-bit Edit+Continue support) when you have the old debugging engine selected.  It is an option: Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Use Managed Compatibility Mode option.  Untick it get it back.

You only really need this option checked to [debug C++/CLI code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19513833/17034).

Comment: Unfortunately I've just confirmed that this box is unticked and I still don't see return values in the Autos window.

Comment: I'm going to award the bounty anyway, because this answer may be useful for someone else in the future and I appreciate any information at all about the feature.