# Unknown function in C# call stack with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

When stopped at a breakpoint in a pure C# project, I can see `<Unknown function>` in the call stack viewer for one of my own functions, and no local variables are available. Optimization is disabled. How can I see the function name and the locals?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512785/debugging-c-cli-unknown-function-and-no-locals

Comment: Could you provide a sample call stack with this mark? I would like to see between which calls it is.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you had the same problem more than a year ago, but here's why I had the same case for some dlls:

I renamed a parent folder of the project and had the problem afterwards. Closing Visual Studio and removing any temporary files as well as the deployment directory fixed it.

Comment: it's not helping :(